# Check if T object has a property and set property

Tags: c#, generics, windows-runtime

Hello i am having a generic method

```
public async Task<T> MyMethod<T>(...)
{
 //logic here...
}
```

i would like inside this method to check if the T object has a specific property and then set a value to this property:

I've tried creating a dynamic object and do something like this:

```
var result = default(T);
dynamic obj = result;

Error error = new Error();
error.Message = "An error occured, please try again later.";
error.Name = "Error";

obj.Errors.Add(error);
result = obj;

return result;
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `default(T)` returns `null` if T is a reference type.  You are trying to create a dynamic object out of null and access properties on it.  You can either pass in an instance of T or instantiate one using the new() generic constraint, but what if it doesn't have a default constructor?

Comment: Why would you not use a generic constraint and an interface that defines the property you need, and forces `T` to have that property?

Comment: I'd like not to force this property.

Comment: That's not really how generics are supposed to be used.  Chances are, you are much better off using a different approach than generics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get a runtime type of the object with `object.GetType`, then you can check if it has a particular property with [`Type.GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx) , and if yes, call [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName");
if (pi != null)
{
    pi.SetValue(obj, value);
}
```

Comment: Why the `await Task.Delay`? Just so the compiler warning goes away?

Answer (score 2):

If you control all the possible types which use `MyMethod`, the easiest option is to create an interface which defines the properties you need:

```
public interface IThing
{
    IList<Error> Errors { get; }
}
```

And change the method signature:

```
public async Task<T> MyMethod<T>(...) where T : IThing
```

If you do that, every item passed in will have to implement your interface and as a result have an `Errors` property.

Comment: Yeah that's good, but how can i check if the passing object has a property? I would like to ignore object that  doesn't have a specific property.